# Replacing smart switch 3 gang box neutrals all tied up

Tags: wiring, switch, light

Just moved in. Have a three gang box trying to replace switches with smart switches (they each require neutral).

I'm unsure though how I'm supposed to wire the neutrals, since they are all bundled up into one wire nut.

I could cram the neutrals in, but that seems dumb and unsafe. Is there a recommended, safe way to do this?
[image: neutrals]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Get a bigger nut/connector (or more of them)

You're right to be concerned about cramming the existing wirenut over its capacity.  The solution, though, is to either use a larger nut/connector (such as an 8-port push-in type connector) or two smaller nuts connected to each other by a piece of white wire of the appropriate gauge.

Comment: Is it okay to put a piece of neutral wire in that existing nut coming out and then tiring the other end to a new nut and connecting the three switches to that?

Comment: @K2xL That is exactly what the 2nd half of "The solution" sentence says. Just make sure that you don't try to put more wires into a wire nut than they're specified to handle. That may mean you actually need _3_ wire nuts to get all your neutrals connected.